# Mail is stuck in outbox when using cached exchange and shared e-mail folders

Tags: exchange-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013

When using Outlook 2013 in Exchange Cached Mode, e-mails sent via shared e-mail accounts are getting stuck in the outbox.

As soon as I disable cached mode, the mails are gone. Has someone experienced this before and fixed this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This has been a problem since Outlook 2003.  The best and only method I know to correct the problem is to turn off "Cached Mode".  I believe there is an issue with Outlook synching in order to send the e-mail.

What `Exchance Cached Mode` does is allow you to be offline or on a slow connection and still have a local copy of your online inbox.  That way you can still work even in an offline state.

When turning it off it will require you to be online and have a decent connection to the Exchange server so be cautious of that.  Another method may be to create a PST file instead which saves your e-mails locally anyway, doing away with the need for Cached Mode.

`Here is the what and how to turn off Cached Mode:`
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/turn-on-or-off-cached-exchange-mode-HP001232935.aspx

`Create PST`
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/create-an-outlook-data-file-pst-to-save-your-information-HA102749405.aspx

Comment: thanks for your answer. Too bad exchange cached mode can't be used because sometimes there's no internet connection available

Comment: Use the PST method then.  That way it allows for you to have the information locally and does not require cached mode.